# How to select nth-child in SASS within a nested selectors

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way not to repeat the clip-item class when using nth-child in a nested SCSS? The output should be in the CSS below.

CSS

```
.clip-item .group-left {
  padding: 0;
}
.clip-item .group-left:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: blue;
}
.clip-item .group-left:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background: gray;
}
.clip-item .group-right {
  padding: 0;
}
.clip-item .group-right:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: blue;
}
.clip-item .group-right:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background: gray;
}
```

I was trying to do it like below. Even though t's working, I don't think it's the right way / clean way.

SCSS

```
.group-left {
  .clip-item & {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .clip-item:nth-child(2n+1) & {
    background: blue;
  }
  .clip-item:nth-child(2n+2) & {
    background: gray;
  }
}

.group-right {
  .clip-item & {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .clip-item:nth-child(2n+1) & {
    background: blue;
  }
  .clip-item:nth-child(2n+2) & {
    background: gray;
  }
}
```

I'm also using the .group-left and .group-right classes in some content, that's why I used it as a parent selector.

EDIT:-
Each group wrappers are wrapped in a clip-item div. Below is my markup:-

```
<div class="clip-item">
  <div class="group-left">
  <div class="group-right">
</div>

<div class="clip-item">
  <div class="group-left">
  <div class="group-right">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to group the selectors in this way - I recommend using the [@at-root directive.](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_at-root__at-root)

> The @at-root directive causes one or more rules to be emitted at the
>   root of the document, rather than being nested beneath their parent
>   selectors.

```
.group-left {
  .clip-item & {
    padding: 0;
  }
  @at-root .clip-item &:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background: blue;
  }
  @at-root .clip-item &:nth-child(2n+2) {
    background: gray;
  }
}

.group-right {
  .clip-item & {
    padding: 0;
  }
  @at-root .clip-item &:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background: blue;
  }
  @at-root .clip-item &:nth-child(2n+2) {
    background: gray;
  }
}
```

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/xpKLdR) (View compiled CSS)

Also, [this CSS-tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/#article-header-id-9) may help:

> The `&` doesn't allow you to selectively traverse up your nested
>   selector tree to a certain place and only use a small portion of the
>   compiled parent selector that you want to use.

---

By the way:

> Even though it's working, I don't think it's the right way

Well actually, your SCSS is not currently producing the requested CSS.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you so much for your response and for the recommendations. I missed to tell that each group wrappers are wrapped in a clip-item div. I've tried the code you've provided, but doesn't work. I've edited my post and added my current markup. Sorry about that.

Comment: @AlexandriaMiguel - I updated the Codepen with your edited markup, but left the SASS as is because the compiled CSS produces exactly what you asked for